# console.log() is not working on Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I developed an add-on for Firefox to Displaying every click event in Firefox browser.but i need to debug my code(JavaScript code) so i used console.log() but it's not Displaying in console(Ctrl+Shift+K)and Firebug console(Ctrl+Shift+J).
I used below snippet,even though am getting an JavaScript prompt as "Cu" is not defined and "require"is not defined

```
const {Cu} = require('chrome');
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm");
```

Comment: @Noitidart I tried it but getting same issue!!!!

Comment: Try `Cu.reportError('blah')`, you are using addon sdk so it does some weird stuff i dont know about

Comment: Thanks once again finally i got with  window.console.log('blah').

Comment: Wow interesting find there